# Using of Alfa AWUS036NHA adapter

Tags: router, kali-linux, usb-network-adapter

I bought an "Alfa AWUS036NHA" USB Wi-Fi adapter today. Is it possible to use this Alfa AWUS036NHA as router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's a USB/WiFi adaptor - https://www.alfa.com.tw/products/awus036nha?variant=36473966166088

You could use the computer you connected to as a router, assuming it has another NIC or wifi connection.